# How to speed up query to Oracle (selection of all table_names that contain FK on the table)

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

Help, please, to speed up query to select all table names and column names that have reference on current table, if I can't change DB rules and structure
 
thank you

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT AC.table_name, ACC.column_name  
FROM 
  all_constraints AC 
  INNER JOIN all_cons_columns ACC 
    ON ACC.table_name = AC.table_name 
       AND  
       ACC.constraint_name = AC.constraint_name  
WHERE 
  AC.r_constraint_name IN  (
    SELECT AC.constraint_name 
    FROM all_constraints AC 
    WHERE 
     table_name='CURRENT_TABLE' 
     AND 
     owner='SOME_DATABASE_NAME'
  )
```

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: Refer below link. There is a code snippet as well to find out different sort of dependencies. 

http://www.dba-oracle.com/d_dba_dependencies.htm

Comment: 1st mention Oracle version you use. Also note that you should compute stats on Oracle dictionary - otherwise (especially on older versions) use RULE based optimizer.

Comment: @AndyLester This query only uses standard data dictionary views, there's no need to post the table and index definitions.  And even the explain plan may not help much - for me it was over 100 steps accessing undocumented tables.  Knowing the number of rows returned might help, but the data distribution really requires knowing the poster's *entire* database.  Tuning even a trivial data dictionary query can be difficult.